# Find first character position in UILabel text line using CoreText Framework in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I'm new in developer I want to image draw on Label text Upside and bottom side of UILabel Text so I need frame of only Label text frame of Label 
[image]
so please describe answer with an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take two `imageview` upside and downside the your label. You can't do that within label. You can resize the label to fit the textsize by,

```
 [yourLabel sizeToFit];
```

It will resize the label according to it's text. And by that you can set your imageview above and below it.